# How to pass json array into java script function and access json array randomly

Tags: json

I have a table named question in database. Table contains four column(q_no, q_id,description,question). I have created json array using blow code.

```
// in php....

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM question";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$a=array(); 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
     $a[]=$row;
}

$b=json_encode($a);  
myfunction($b)
{
}
```

Java script function is :

```
// inside script
function myfuction(x)
{
   // how to access x[2].description
}
```

Now question is how to pass $b  into a java script function and how to access value of particular column of particular row ?????

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
echo "<script> a = $b; alert(a[0].description); </script>";
```